# Java: An UUID generating Singleton

Tags: java, random, static, singleton, uuid

I'm working on a school project that's like a simpler Youtube clone. I know one of the attributes of the Video and Playlist classes is a String code, which I can generate in whatever way I want, as long as it's always unique. So I tougth to use UUID (tough I'm fairly new to it), and thing is a video and a playlist can have the same code, because they are in different libraries in my code, so in theory I'd want 2 UUID generators, one for videos, one for playlists, so the codes can overlap that way.

I thought  to make a singleton so there's no more generators than those I need, and I can always assure I get unique codes. Here's what I got.

```java
import java.util.UUID;

public class CodeGenerator {

    private static CodeGenerator singleInstance = null;

    private UUID videoGen;
    private UUID listGen;

    private CodeGenerator() {
    }

    public static CodeGenerator getInstance() {
        if (singleInstance == null) 
            singleInstance = new CodeGenerator(); 

        return singleInstance;
    }

    public String getCodeVideo() {
        return videoGen.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getCodePlaylist() {
        return listGen.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

But Eclipse is warning me in both of my gets that I should change this instance-reference to a static reference and I've never really been good at static stuff, and since I want to get rid of all these code warning for my project, can anyone tell me a fix that does what I'm looking for?

P.S I try to generate some codes in a Test class with the two different methods, and they always come out different and such as expected. The code is woring fine and I can see, but I'm scared down the line it might give me problems.

Comment: `randomUUID()` is a `static` method, calling it on an instance (that you didn't even initialize correctly) makes no sense. That's what Eclipse is telling you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't anything to do with your singleton - it's because you're calling `UUID.randomUUID()`, which is a static method, as if it were an instance method.

Here's a shorter example which I'd expect to give the same warning:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UUID ignored = null;
        UUID generated = ignored.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

Fundamentally, your fields are pointless - you're never assigning a value to them anyway.

It's not clear to me whether you expect `getCodeVideo()` to always return the same string for the lifetime of your process. If that *is* the case, you should change the code to something like:

```java
import java.util.UUID;

public class CodeGenerator {

    private static CodeGenerator singleInstance = new CodeGenerator();

    private String video;
    private String codePlayList;

    private CodeGenerator() {
        video = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        codePlayList = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public static CodeGenerator getInstance() {
        return singleInstance;
    }

    public String getCodeVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public String getCodePlayList() {
        return codePlayList;
    }
}
```

If you actually want to generate a new string each time you call the method, you don't need a singleton or anything like it:

```java
import java.util.UUID;

public class CodeGenerator {
    public static String generateCode() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I want everytime I call getCodeVideo() to return a different String, but I also want getCodePlaylist() to be able to return Strings that have been returned by getCodeVideo().

Comment: So even with 2 UUID, I can't get two sets of codes so to say? It's not a big deal, as long as the codes are always unique, the code would work, but I kinda wanted to have the two sets of codes.

Comment: @Catralitos Having two calls is fine--but you see you're doing the same thing in each one--there's zero difference--(currently) it's simply a matter of communication to the developer (and a point of extensibility). You could pre/append a "c"/"v" to indicate a video or playlist, of course, which might be useful as a simple, visual indicator.